# ExtJS Parsing Date Incorrectly

Tags: extjs, extjs3

When I enter "31/12/2012" in my field (date format is MM/DD/YYYY), it changes the date to "7/12/2014" in the field. I would rather it error with a "not valid" error message.

I have inherited this code from a previous developer:

```
function dateRangeCheck(val, field) {
    field.vtypeText = '';

    var date = field.parseDate(val);
    if (!date) {
        field.vtypeText = val + ' is not a valid date - it must be in the format (MM/DD/YYYY).';
        return false;
    }

    var retVal = true;

    if (field.fromField) {
        var fromField = Ext.getCmp(field.fromField);
        var fromDate = fromField.parseDate(fromField.getValue());
        // If we don't have a fromDate to validate with then return true
        if (!fromDate)
            return true;

        retVal = (date >= fromDate);

        if (retVal)
            fromField.clearInvalid();
    }
    else if (field.toField) {
        var toField = Ext.getCmp(field.toField);
        var toDate = toField.parseDate(toField.getValue());
        // If we don't have a toDate to validate with then return true
        if (!toDate)
            return true;

        retVal = (date <= toDate);

        if (retVal)
            toField.clearInvalid();
    }

    if (!retVal) {
        field.vtypeText = 'From Date must be less than or equal to To Date.';
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

When I try to use the default 'daterange' vtype, as soon as I type a "3" in the field, it throws a JS runtime exception 'object doesn't support this property or method'.

Comment: Are you using ExtJS4? Using the Ext.form.field.Date component?

Comment: I'm not sure. The only reference I can find to an ExtJS version is 3.0 RC 1.1.

Comment: You can get the version by typing `Ext.version || Ext.getVersion().version` into the console with Ext loaded

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can set `Date.useStrict = true` globally and the DateField will use that by default.

[image]

For Ext 4+ it would be `Ext.Date.useStrict = true` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your call to `parseDate` just needs to have the [strict switch](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Date-static-method-parseDate) set.

> `strict` (optional) True to validate date strings while parsing (i.e.
>   prevents javascript Date "rollover")(defaults to false). Invalid date
>   strings will return null when parsed.

```
> Date.parseDate('31/12/2012','m/d/Y')
  Sat Jul 12 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
> Date.parseDate('31/12/2012','m/d/Y', true)
  null
```

The `parseDate` method in DateField is private and undocumented, and the [discussion](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?72326-CLOSED-3.0rc2-Need-to-be-able-to-have-strict-date-parsing-in-DateField) to allow strict date parsing in ExtJS 3.x never bore any fruit. I think your best bet is to use an override to allow strict date parsing.

```
// before you use your DateFields
Ext.override(Ext.form.DateField, {
    safeParse : function(value, format) {
        if (Date.formatContainsHourInfo(format)) {
            // if parse format contains hour information, no DST adjustment is necessary
            return Date.parseDate(value, format, this.strict);
        } else {
            // set time to 12 noon, then clear the time
            var parsedDate = Date.parseDate(value + ' ' + this.initTime, format + ' ' + this.initTimeFormat, this.strict);

            if (parsedDate) {
                return parsedDate.clearTime();
            }
        }
    }
});

//... and in your DateField config:  
strict: true,
```

Comment: I found a definition of parseDate in ext-all-debug.js. The header of the file says: "Ext JS Library 3.0 RC 1.1". The definition is on line 6051. I'm not great with javascript and there are a lot of references to other functions and properties. I'm trying to trace through it.

Comment: I just looked through the `Ext.form.DateField` code and there *is* a `parseDate` method, it's just private and undocumented. I think you'll need to handle this with an override then. I'll update my answer shortly.